# What will be the shape of data, when you use batch_size for LSTM?

Tags: lstm, batchsize

batch_size = 10
I have 1000 samples(rows) and 2 features(columns). I want to give this data to LSTM model,Which allows 3-Dimensional data shape.
Will my data get reshaped by : (10,1000,2) or shaped by  : (10,10,2) for every iteration?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nn.LSTM in PyTorch, the input data shape is `(seq_len, batch_size, input_size)` at each iteration, assuming you set nn.LSTM(`batch_first=True`), then the input data shape is `(batch_size, seq_len, input_size)`, the answer below is based on `batch_first=True`.

If you need to use the first 100 samples to predict the next 10 samples, then `seq_len=100`, and the input data shape is `(10, 100, 2)`.

The general data processing method can refer to the following code (assuming the first column is a timestamp):

```py
def load_data(file_name):
    """
    :return: dataframe
    """
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/data/' + file_name
    df = pd.read_csv(path, encoding='gbk')
    df.fillna(df.mean(), inplace=True)

    return df


class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.data[item]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)


# seq_len=100, pred_step_size=10
def nn_seq(seq_len, B, pred_step_size):
    data = load_data('mtl_data_1.csv')
    # split
    train = data[:int(len(data) * 0.6)]
    val = data[int(len(data) * 0.6):int(len(data) * 0.8)]
    test = data[int(len(data) * 0.8):len(data)]
    # normalization
    train.drop([train.columns[0]], axis=1, inplace=True)
    val.drop([val.columns[0]], axis=1, inplace=True)
    test.drop([test.columns[0]], axis=1, inplace=True)
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    train = scaler.fit_transform(train.values)
    val = scaler.transform(val.values)
    test = scaler.transform(test.values)

    def process(dataset, batch_size, step_size, shuffle):
        dataset = dataset.tolist()
        seq = []
        for i in range(0, len(dataset) - seq_len - pred_step_size, step_size):
            train_seq = []
            for j in range(i, i + seq_len):
                x = []
                for c in range(len(dataset[0])):
                    x.append(dataset[j][c])
                train_seq.append(x)

            train_labels = []
            for j in range(len(dataset[0])):
                train_label = []
                for k in range(i + seq_len, i + seq_len + pred_step_size):
                    train_label.append(dataset[k][j])
                train_labels.append(train_label)
            
            train_seq = torch.FloatTensor(train_seq)
            train_labels = torch.FloatTensor(train_labels)
            seq.append((train_seq, train_labels))

        seq = MyDataset(seq)
        seq = DataLoader(dataset=seq, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=shuffle, num_workers=0, drop_last=True)

        return seq

    Dtr = process(train, B, step_size=1, shuffle=True)
    Val = process(val, B, step_size=1, shuffle=True)
    Dte = process(test, B, step_size=pred_step_size, shuffle=False)

    return Dtr, Val, Dte, scaler
```